# Pandas return column value if other column value is equal

Tags: python, csv, pandas

so recentyl im trying to get data from CSV file using python and pandas.
Code should return or print data from colum 1 if data from column 2 is equal to some string.

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('alerts.csv', sep=';', encoding='latin1')

print(df[['color']['item']].loc[['color']=='red'])
```

but its seems not working with strings ?

Comment: Provide your sample data, few rows, above, for others to understand.

Comment: color| sth    | item
:----- | -----: | :----:
red   |    x   | bike 

it should return bike

Answer (score 0):

you are not using .loc correctly

.loc need an indexer, and columns such has

```
indexer = df[df['color']=='red'].index
print(df.loc[indexer,'item'])
```

Comment: output:
Series([], Name: item, dtype: object)

it should be equal to some value

Comment: Since I don't have access to your data it's very hard to debug your problem. check what `df[df['color']=='red'].index` returns. try `print(indexer)`

Comment: example of csv: 
|color| sth | item|
  red     x      bike 
   blue  x       pen 
 red     x        car 

and should return bike and car for example